# Why is my mount command failing in an Ubuntu VM?

Tags: server, mount, virtualbox, samba

I am on a computer using Windows 7, service pack 1.

On the host Windows system, I have done the following:

- I have installed Oracle VirtualBox Version 5.2.0 r118431 (Qt5.6.2).
- I have used VirtualBox to create a 32-bit Ubuntu server virtual
  machine, using all default settings.
- I have created a folder on the Windows host system at the path
  C:\sharedFolder.
- I have configured a shared folder in VirtualBox for the Ubuntu server
  virtual machine called "sharedFolder" at the path C:\sharedFolder. 
  (Not auto-mount, not read only.)
- I have loaded the 32-bit Ubuntu server virtual machine with Ubuntu
  17.10 32-bit server, creating a guest Ubuntu system.

On the guest Ubuntu system, I have done the following:

- I have installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions for Linux using the
  following command:

  **sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso**
- I have created a group called "vboxsf" and confirmed that my user is a member of that group.
- I have created a folder in my home folder called "shared_folder" with
  permissions set wide open to 777.
- I have ATTEMPTED to mount the shared folder "sharedFolder" designated
  in VirtualBox to the "~/shared_folder" folder in my home directory
  using the following command:

  **sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=1000,gid=1000 sharedFolder ~/shared_folder**

This ATTEMPTED mount command has failed every time with the following error:

```
mount: /home/<user_name>/shared_folder: mount(2) System call failed: Protocol error.
```

I have attempted to perform the mount with Sharing turned off and Sharing wide-open on the folder at C:\sharedFolder on the host Windows system.

What am I doing that is causing the mount command to fail?

Comment: Have you tried the automount option under the menu item Devices/Shared Folders/Shared Folders Settings?